# Not able to search element for Desktop app with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, desktop-application, winappdriver

I am automating the Desktop App which Microsoft based app. Application design is created with many custom view. I am trying to find the element with the tools like Inspect.exe,UISpy.exe. VisualUIAVerify but from all the 3 options I am not able to find the element. Using Inspect.exe I am getting the details but using that Selenium is not performing the actions.

**Inspect.exe is showing like this :**
[image]

**And My Application UI is Like this:**

[image]

I want to click on the Highlight Image. But I am not getting any identification for that.

If anyone can help me out with this then it would be gratefull.

Comment: wait why are you using selenium for a desktop app? If you want to perform clicks on an element, you should use pywinauto or others via python

Comment: As per the company request, we have to go for selenium.

Comment: Umm. Selenium is made for WebGUI not desktop GUI. It uses id, cssselector, xpaths.. no doubt some desktop elements might have an id but they are dynamic and not reliable. And even then, most of them can't be retrieved. There are better and easier solutions available, try suggesting that..

Comment: Yes, that's the problem few of the elements are not getting retrieved. Could you just tell me which are the best options for automating desktop app?

Comment: I'm in no place to suggest. However, these suggestions by @VasilyRyabov might be useful. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/16273 I believe he also develops Pywinauto which I very often use.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the class name find all the elements and then use the indexing to click on the second element.

```
IList<WindowsElement> allElement = _driver.FindElementsByClassName("Image");
```